# MySql Pivotal table query group by multiple columns

Tags: mysql, pivot

The below MySQL table looking something like this below.

```
consulted_on (DATE)   consulted_by (VARCHAR)
---------------------------------------------
04/12/2018               Mr.Bob
04/12/2018               Mr.Jhon
04/12/2018               Mr.Bob
05/12/2018               Mr.Jhon
06/12/2018               Mr.Bob
06/12/2018               Mr.Jhon
07/12/2018               Mr.Bob
```

I would like to display the data as below , Is it possible to get the output like below ?

```
consulted_on(DATE)  Mr.Bob   Mr.Jhon  
-------------------------------------
04/12/2018           2              1
05/12/2018           0              1
06/12/2018           1              1
07/12/2018           1              0
```

The consulted_by column is basically contains dynamic value, in this case how do I write pivot query in mysql ? can any one help me with this ?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use Below query:

```
SELECT
  consulted_on,  
  SUM(CASE WHEN (consulted_by='Mr.Bob') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Mr_Bob,
  SUM(CASE WHEN (consulted_by='Mr.Jhon') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Mr_Jhon,
FROM table_name
GROUP BY consulted_on
```

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply, but the column consulted_by is the dynamic one